# Error code 0x8007267C while activating Window 10

Tags: windows-10

How do I resolve this?

[image: Click to see Image]

> We can't activate Windows on this device as we can't connect to your organization's activation server. Make sure you're connected to your organization's network and try again. If you continue having problems with activation, contact your organization's support person. 
>  Error code:`0x80007267C`

Comment: … and have you contacted your organisation for help with this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot - that's a [KMS key](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kmsclientkeys), meant for when you're authenticating against a central key management server.

KMS licences last about 180 days before they need to connect to the server - after which you see this.

If its a personal system - someone either made a mistake configuring it, or installed it against a licence server you can no longer connect to. There's not much you can do, since a KMS licence is *not* for personal use. Its meant for organisations to easily manage a fleet of systems.

If its a work system, your sysadmin or technical support team could help - it may be as simple as connecting to your workplace VPN in some cases.